# How do I calibrate a Gamecube controller?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-gamecube

I want to play Ocarina of Time on my Wii with a gamecube controller, but the joystick isn't cooperating and I keep going in the opposite direction than I want to go!

How can I recalibrate it so that I walk the way I want to?

Answer (score 9):

> Like most analog controllers, the GameCube controller self-calibrates when the console is switched on, setting the current analog stick and L and R buttons' positions as "neutral," which may cause problems if the controls are not actually in their neutral position during calibration. Holding down X, Y and start/pause for three seconds at any time will recalibrate the controller. Unplugging and reconnecting the controller, and in the case of the wireless WaveBird controller, turning the controller off and back on, will also force a recalibration.

Source: [Wii Wikia](http://wii.wikia.com/wiki/GameCube_Controller)